# Apache Flink GCS FileSink poor performance due to many small files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, apache-flink, streaming, flink-streaming

I'm working on an apache-flink (v 1.17.2) streaming application, where my file-sink is Google Cloud Storage. The performance is very poor and my task manager/s are 100% busy. I believe it is related to the problem that it writes too much small files to .inprogress temporary files. With checkpointing enabled (75 seconds), it writes up to 220 files to .inprogress state just for one part. With 1 task manager it writes up to 500 events/s to a cloud storage, I'm also using avro format for the output file.

This is my definition of the filesink

```scala
val sink: FileSink[Click] = FileSink
    .forBulkFormat(new Path(""), AvroWriters.forSpecificRecord(classOf[Click]))
    .withBucketAssigner(new ObjectStorageBucketAssigner())
    .withRollingPolicy(OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build())
    .build()
```

I've tried changing following configurations: `state.backend.fs.memory-threshold`, `state.backend.fs.write-buffer-size`, `taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers`, `taskmanager.network.memory.buffer-debloat.enabled`

In practice there was no impact on the performance.
What could be done to change this behavior and improve the performance (throughput) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `state.backend.xxx` settings are for saving state to the file system, and don't have anything to do with your file sink.
2. If your Task Managers are 100% busy, the problem probably isn't with your file sink. There's something in your workflow that is causing the high CPU load.

Comment: There is no intermediate processing in between source and sink. I did a comparison with s3 and without any tuning I was able to achieve 25 000 events/s on S3. I’ve also enabled logging at the TRACE level and saving inprogress files are the most time expensive operations from what I’ve observed. I’ve also checked AvroParquetWriter, and on GCS I was able to get around 7000 events/s.

Comment: Turn on flamegraphs and see what's using CPU cycles...

Comment: Hey kkrugler, I have found that this is an issue with the implementation of the AvroWriter for specific records with GCS API implementation. It flushes data every 64kbit and flush is implemented as closing file and opening new one with recoverable writer. I've checked this against s3 part-file implementation and I can easily achieve around 15k/s without any tuning.

Comment: What's your job's parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file compaction feature described [here in the docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/#file-compaction) is relevant to your situation.